# Difficulty upgrade from version 3.4.1 to 4.5.2

Tags: sonarqube

Hi I'm trying to upgrade Sonarqube from 3.4.1 to 4.5.2 but had some issues.

I ensured that the sonar.properties file and the wrapper.conf file were both the same and changed them accordingly on the newer version. To install it we simply moved 4.5.2 onto the server and changed the symlink, this worked until it tried to upgrade the database then it stated 'Upgrade is impossible'

After this we couldn't get Sonar to start again, so we rolled it back to a previous version..

So our current predicament is whether or not to create a new version of Sonar on the latest version or to slowly upgrade the old one but from 3.4.1 to 3.4.2 etc..

What would you suggest?

Thanks

Comment: Have you followed the upgrade guide? (http://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/upgrading.html) What do you get in the logs? (please update your question with the content of the log to see the error)

Comment: have you made sure your plugins were all updated correctly? Since the [Java Plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Java+Plugin) is causing some trouble when updating without removing some other plugins first. Also [FindBugs Plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Findbugs+Plugin) may causes problems since you will need java 7 or higher within the latest plugin version (java 6 is not supported anymore)

Comment: Fixed issue now, had to point it to a new database, as was getting Database errors too